# heat pump air handler blower motor stalls at start up randomly

Tags: hvac

[image][image]
The air handler blower sounds like it is being switched off and on rapidly but will eventually run. This occurs randomly at start up.  Most of the time it starts and runs fine.  Could the capacitor be going bad or what could cause this?has capacitor in front that connects to motor in blower

Comment: Check the connections on the blower relay and control circuit.  It sounds like something's loose in there somewhere.

Comment: Is this a conventional capacitor-based blower motor, or an electronically commutated blower motor?  Can you post the wiring diagram for your air handler please?

Comment: That's a great start. Can you add a readable pic of the low voltage wiring side of the label, too? Not sure if it'll be 100% necessary, but it certainly can't hurt.

Comment: didn't find any loose connections

Comment: bad electronic board (fan relay)